# Dynamic positioning of iOS objects in a Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, interface-builder, storyboard

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically position objects in a DetailView storyboard.

For starters, the app follows a traditional blog format, in which the MasterView is a UITableView (or UICollectionView) with multiple posts.

When the user taps on one of them, a segue leads to the DetailView.

Everything loads correctly, except for the positioning of the elements in the DetailView.

This is how it looks:

[image]

The top `UIImageView` has fixed height so it does not overlap with the `Post Text Label`.

However, `Post Text Label` has variable height as some post texts are longer than others. This is taken care of by a category I am using that dynamically resizes it (`resizeToFit`). This all works great.

The problem now is that as the `Post Text Label` grows vertically, I need the `View - Byline` (green rectangle) to move downwards based on `Post Text Label`'s vertical size. And I just can't make it move downwards.

You can see that I placed all of the `View - Byline` objects inside a View, so they move together by targeting only the `View - Byline` to programmatically change position.

Do you know of any method I can use to accomplish this? Any pointers, tutorials or wisdom are greatly appreciated.

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *postThumbView;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postTextLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *postAuthorPictureView;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postAuthorNameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postTimestampLabel;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UIView       *postBylineView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
...
[postThumbView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postThumbUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

[postAuthorPictureView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authorPicture] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

postTextLabel.text  = postText;
postTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(postTextLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                 postThumbView.frame.origin.y + postThumbView.frame.size.height,
                                 postTextLabel.frame.size.width,
                                 postTextLabel.frame.size.height);
[postTextLabel resizeToFit];

postAuthorNameLabel.text = postAuthorName;
postTimestampLabel.text  = postTimestamp;
```

Comment: Are you using iOS 6+ with AutoLayout or iOS 4.3+ with AutoResizing Masks? I ask because iOS 6+ with AutoLayout will do what you require very easily.

Comment: @RoboticCat I'm using ios6 - i've been keeping the "use autolayout" box checked but haven't noticed it make a difference in my problem - how should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting ios6, you should check out autolayout constraints. If not, can't you use the same approach you already did to reposition postTextLabel. So for postByLine, position it relative to the bottom of post textLabel.

```
postByLine.frame = CGRectMake(postByLine.frame.origin.x,
                                      postTextLabel.frame.origin.y + postTextLabel.frame.size.height,
                                      postByLine.frame.size.width,
                                      postByLine.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: do I need to turn off autolayout for this to work? I actually have it on, and see no effect from your code - I had tried this before and can't figure out why it would work for `postTextLabel` but not for the other element (`postByline`)

Comment: yea i think so, also make sure autoresize subviews is disabled/not checked for postByLine's superview. However,since you're using ios6 please consider looking into constraints http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

Comment: clip subviews shouldn't have any effect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think reading the [post recommended by @edwin](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2) is important to understand AutoLayout.

For example, although I had AutoLayout ON in my storyboard, the elements weren't adjusting their position as expected.

The issue (addressed in the post linked above) is that AutoLayout expects you to initially position your elements next to each other within a certain distance threshold, otherwise it will not create (and maintain) a relationship between them.

If you look at my original post above, you'll see the green rectangle (post byline). It was not moving down as the post text increased in vertical size.

That was because when I initially created the byline box, I placed it too far from the bottom boundary of post text label. Once I dragged it closer, an h-shaped icon appeared between the 2 elements indicating a relationship was created.

Then everything worked as expected. Most default distance thresholds are around 8 points, but once you establish the relationship, you can later increase the distance as you see fit.

Comment: Note that you can also manually create a relationship between two views by selecting the two views, going to the "Contstraints" button at the bottom, and choosing "Pin Vertical Spacing"